# everytime i am getting an error when i send request to server for File uploading using Form data

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Client side code is as below

```
    $scope.mbr= function(event){
    var formdata = new FormData();  
var reader = new FileReader();  
var url = '/mbr_replace' ;  
var upload_file = $(event.target[0].files[0]; 
        formdata.append('mbrpdf',upload_file );
$http.post(url,formdata).success(function(response){alert("Got Response!!!!!!");
        }); 
    }
```

server side code is as below

```
app.post('/mbr_replace', isLoggedIn,upload.single('mbrpdf'),users.replace_pdf,  maintain.userstudys, function(req,res){
    res.send("Succeed !!!")
```

});

## error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

```
at parse (D:\ManiKandan\Heta_Dev_3030\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:82:15)
at D:\ManiKandan\Heta_Dev_3030\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:116:18
at invokeCallback (D:\ManiKandan\Heta_Dev_3030\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:262:16)
at done (D:\ManiKandan\Heta_Dev_3030\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:251:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (D:\ManiKandan\Heta_Dev_3030\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:307:7)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parentheses and this line: `var upload_file = $(event.target[0].files[0]; ` that may be causing issues.

Comment: okay !  @RobynCute....  as you told i was changed that closing parentheses ..but still i am getting same error ...

Comment: now i its working properly.but i don't know  what is the error and how it was solved ?